# how to merge same object arrays based on same key's value in array of object ,incase of multiple matches found then merge based on priority using Js

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

how to merge  same object arrays based on same key's value in array of object ,incase of multiple matches found then merge based on priority

consider

```
a = [
  { x: 'all', y: 'tablename', z: 'schema' },
  { x: 'all1', y: 'tablename', z: 'schema' },
  { x: 'all2', y: 'tablename', z: 'schema' },
  { x: 'al52', y: 'tablename', z: 'schema' },
];

b = [
  { x1: 'all', y1: 'tablename', z1: 'schema' },
  { x1: 'all', y1: 'tablename1', z1: 'schema1' },
  { x1: 'all1', y1: 'tablename1', z1: 'schema1' },
  { x1: 'all', y1: 'tablename3', z1: 'schema' },
  { x1: 'all1', y1: 'tablename2', z1: 'schema1' },
];

priority = [
  { y1: 'tablename3', z1: 'schema' },
  { y1: 'tablename1', z1: 'schema1' },
  { y1: 'tablename2', z1: 'schema' },
  { y1: 'tablename', z1: 'schema' },
];

expected = [
  {
    x: 'all',
    y: 'tablename',
    z: 'schema',
    x1: 'all',
    y1: 'tablename3',
    z1: 'schema',
  },
  {
    x: 'all1',
    y: 'tablename1',
    z: 'schema1',
    x1: 'all1',
    y1: 'tablename1',
    z1: 'schema1',
  },
];
```

in above object array 'a' will always have x as unique  value.
I have tried below

```
Actual = [
  {
    x: 'all',
    x1: 'all',
    y: 'tablename',
    y1: 'tablename',
    z: 'schema',
    z1: 'schema',
  },
  {
    x: 'all1',
    x1: 'all1',
    y: 'tablename',
    y1: 'tablename1',
    z: 'schema',
    z1: 'schema1',
  },
];
```

Which is wrong  Please advise how to resolve this

```
var c = [];
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < b.length; j++) {
    if (a[i].x === b[j].x1) {
      var combinedObj = {
        x: a[i].x,
        y: a[i].y,
        z: a[i].z,
        x1: b[j].x1,
        y1: b[j].y1,
        z1: b[j].z1,
      };
      c.push(combinedObj);
      break;
    }
  }
}
console.log(c);
```

Comment: You have not fully explained how the priority check works

Comment: Not clear. Why `{ x: 'all1', y: 'tablename1',` as second object, when those key/values never appear in the same object. Why does expected result have 2 entries?